# Is inconsistent tone in a thriller always a bad thing?

Tags: creative-writing, tone, thriller

I've heard that changing tone is a bad thing, because we're expected to remain consistent in tone, but I am wondering if this is really true and if there can be exception to the rule.

For example, in my thriller, the story starts off as a slow-burn psychological suspense, and then transitions into a more action-oriented, high-stakes thriller halfway through, the change in tone reflect the escalation of danger and intensity, and then at the end the story shifts to a slice-of-life comedy. Is there anything wrong with my plan?

Comment: What purpose do these tonal shifts have? Is there a reason you want to shift the story's tone so drastically at the end?

Comment: The shift is intended to provide a cathartic release for the audience. It would allow the audience to experience a sense of closure and emotional release after feeling tense.